# How to pass system property to map function in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, configuration, mapreduce, hbase

is there a way how to pass system parameter (something like -Dmy_param=XXX) to map function in hadoop map reduce framework.
Submission of job to hadoop cluster is done via .setJarByClass().
In mapper I have to create configuration so I would like to make it configerable so I thought that standard way via property file would be ok. Just struggling with passing parameter where the  property is set. Another way would be to add property file to submitted jar. Does someone have an experience how solve that?

Comment: So, you want to pass a property file to each of the mappers?

Comment: yes. Let me explain more. Our mappers are accessing data in HBase that means we need to create configuration in map function. For the purpose of testing etc. we don't what the configuration to have it hardcoded. I am not sure if this is the best approach if there is any better way for integration HBase hadoop mapreduce.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you haven't already used this in your job, you can try GenericOptionsParser, Tool, and ToolRunner for running Hadoop Job.

**Note:** the MyDriver extends Configured and implements Tool.
And, to run you job use this

```
hadoop -jar somename.jar MyDriver -D your.property=value arg1 arg2
```

For more information, [check this link](http://randomzone.in/2013/03/27/genericoptionsparser-tool-and-toolrunner-for-running-hadoop-job/).

**Here's some sample code I prepared for you:**

```java
public class MyDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

  public static class MyDriverMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, NullWritable> {

    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      // In the mapper you can retrieve any configuration you've set
      // while starting the job from the terminal as shown below

      Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
      String yourPropertyValue = conf.get("your.property");
    }
  }

  public static class MyDriverReducer extends Reducer<LongWritable, NullWritable, LongWritable, NullWritable> {

    protected void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<NullWritable> values, Context context) 
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      // --- some code ---
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new MyDriver(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
  }

  @Override
  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = getConf();
    // if you want you can get/set to conf here too.
    // your.property can also be file location and after
    // you retrieve the properties and set them one by one to conf object.

    // --other code--//
    Job job = new Job(conf, "My Sample Job");
    // --- other code ---//
    return (job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: imports are missing from code. Link is 404.  What is package for Configuration class?