# Meaning of context.getconfiguration in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have this doubt in code of searching by argument.

what is the meaning of  `context.getConfiguration().get("Uid2Search");`

```
package SearchTxnByArg;

// This is the Mapper Program for SearchTxnByArg
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class MyMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text>{

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String Txn = value.toString();
            String TxnParts[] = Txn.split(",");
            String Uid = TxnParts[2];
            String Uid2Search = context.getConfiguration().get("Uid2Search");
            if(Uid.equals(Uid2Search))
            {
                context.write(null, value); 
            }           
        }
    }
```

Driver Program

```
package SearchTxnByArg;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class MyDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("Uid2Search", args[0]);        
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Map Reduce Search Txn by Arg");
        job.setJarByClass(MyDriver.class);
        job.setMapperClass(MyMap.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: seems like Uid2Search is application specific property. If you see driver program or command line interface where you are executing the job you will get to know this. Advise you to post such code snippet also to give more clarity to answers.

Comment: what is the purpose of flagging and how to do that?
i do not do post much on stack overflow :D

Comment: ok,  thank you for the advice. I ll keep that in mind.

Comment: I already did that and now i am below 15 reputation. So, I guess i can not do much on ticking flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you have written your driver program. But in my experience,
If you are trying to get system property either by using -D option from the command line or by `System.setproperty` method by default these values will be set to context configuration.

- [As per documentation,](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html)

> Configurations are specified by resources. A resource contains a set
>   of name/value pairs as XML data. Each resource is named by either a
>   String or by a Path. If named by a String, then the classpath is
>   examined for a file with that name. If named by a Path, then the local
>   filesystem is examined directly, without referring to the classpath.
>
> Unless explicitly turned off, Hadoop by default specifies two
>   resources, loaded in-order from the classpath: core-default.xml :
>   Read-only defaults for hadoop. core-site.xml: Site-specific
>   configuration for a given hadoop installation. Applications may add
>   additional resources, which are loaded subsequent to these resources
>   in the order they are added.

[Please see this answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759826/how-to-pass-system-property-to-map-function-in-hadoop)

Context object: allows the Mapper/Reducer to interact with the rest of the Hadoop system. It includes configuration data for the job as well as interfaces which allow it to emit output.

Applications can use the Context:

- to report progress
- to set application-level status messages
- update Counters
- indicate they are alive
- ***to get the values that are stored in job configuration across map/reduce phase.***

Comment: I Have add the driver program also.

Comment: yes I am right! You are adding your input argument like this         conf.set("Uid2Search", args[0]);        
and this parameter passed is available to your mapper using context.getConfiguration().get("Uid2Search") same thing also will be available to reducer also using context object. Please note that Mapper & Reducer are executed in cluster side hence through context.getConguration you are passing application specific parameters. In this case you are trying to compare this parameter with mappers input record parameter. Hope you understood this.